# Enable tree view navigation in SharePoint 2013 Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, navigation, publishing, team-sites

I have created a team site in SharePoint Online - O365 and enabled the Publishing Feature in it. Also, from the site settings I have enabled the Tree View option from the left navigation. But it does not show the quick launch in the tree view form.

Is there any method using which we can have a tree view style left navigation in Team site with publishing feature enabled. 
Please provide your valuable help.

Comment: Please check once you master page, If any custom css you applied to hide the Quick launch . And make sure you enabled the Quick launch in site settings page . And be clear about tree view and Quick lainch , both are different .

Answer (score 1):

Quick Launch and Tree View are in fact two different things when it comes to SharePoint Navigation. You can enable both, or either - from the Site Navigation Settings. While Quick Launch is customizable via the GUI, the Tree View is not.

So if you're not seeing the Quick Launch, most likely it's not enabled from the Site Navigation settings.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Display the Tree View in the Quick Launch bar for your reference:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/display-the-tree-view-in-the-quick-launch-bar-95afa28b-d85a-4cdf-8ffe-3200dafae46c?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us